# How would you determining angle and scale from the phase correlation?

Tags: python, fft

I have recently read this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12253475/6223663 which explains how to get the phase correlation from two images. How would you determine the angle and scale after calculating the phase correlation.

From my understanding it should be similar to with transformations where you get the maximum point in the phase correlation but I do not know how to convert this into an angle and scale.

Comment: Is this a programming or math question?

Comment: I would like to implement this in Python, in the link I included how the phase correlation was computed using Python and I would like to extend on this by  determining the angle and scale in Python